# Excel download does not start

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, radzen

I am working on a Blazor Server application. There is a razor page I am uploading Excel with Radzen Upload component.

Here is the component I am using. (I only share the codes of the relevant parts so that there is no complexity)

```
<div class="col" style="border-left: 0.1rem solid black !important;">
     <h4 class="mb-4">Upload Reconciliation With Excel</h4>
     <RadzenUpload Url="upload/single" Progress=@TrackProgress Complete=@CompleteUpload class="w-100" Error=@(args => UploadError(args)) />
     <RadzenProgressBar Value=@progress class="mt-4" Visible=@showProgress Mode="ProgressBarMode.Indeterminate" />
     <RadzenLabel Visible=@showComplete class="mt-4" Text="Upload Complete!"/>
     <RadzenLabel Visible=@showError class="mt-4" Text="Error occurred, contact Admin!" id="errorlabel"/>
</div>
```

And here is the upload complete method. Displays the number of records uploaded.

```
void CompleteUploadStock(UploadCompleteEventArgs args)
{
     showProgressStock = false;
     showErrorStock = false;
     showCompleteStock = true;
     completeMessage = args.RawResponse + " records inserted to the stocks.";

}
```

There is no problem with the Excel upload. Here is the upload controller.

```
[DisableRequestSizeLimit]
public class UploadController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment env;
    private readonly ILogger<UploadController> logger;
    private readonly IAddStocksUseCase _stocksUseCase;
    private readonly IAddStockUniqueSerialPinUseCase _stockUniqueSerialPinUseCase;
    private readonly IDeleteReconciliationsUseCase _deleteReconciliationsUseCase;
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
    
    public UploadController(IWebHostEnvironment env,
        IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<UploadController> logger, IAddStocksUseCase stocksUseCase, IDeleteReconciliationsUseCase deleteReconciliationsUseCase, IAddStockUniqueSerialPinUseCase stockUniqueSerialPinUseCase)
    {
        this.env = env;
        this.logger = logger;
        _stocksUseCase = stocksUseCase;
        _deleteReconciliationsUseCase = deleteReconciliationsUseCase;
        this.configuration = configuration;
        _stockUniqueSerialPinUseCase = stockUniqueSerialPinUseCase;
     
    }


    // POST: Upload
    [HttpPost("upload/stock")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Stock(IFormFile file)
    {
        try
        {
            var count = await UploadStocksFile(file);
            if (count < 0) { count = 0; }
            return StatusCode(200, count);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private FileStreamResult DownloadExcel(List<GameBank> gameList)
    {
        return Export(gameList);
    }

    
    public async Task<int> UploadStocksFile(IFormFile file)
    {
        var untrustedFileName = file.FileName;
        var totalRows = 0;
        var duplicates = 0;
        try
        {
            var path = Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath,
                env.EnvironmentName, "unsafe_uploads_stock",
                untrustedFileName);

            await using FileStream fs = new(path, FileMode.Create);
            await file.CopyToAsync(fs);

            logger.LogInformation("{untrustedFileName} saved at {Path}",
                untrustedFileName, path);

            var fi = new FileInfo(path);
            // Check if the file exists
            if (!fi.Exists)
                throw new Exception("File " + path + " Does Not Exists");

            //Check if file is an Excel File
            if (untrustedFileName.Contains(".xls"))
            {
                using var ms = new MemoryStream();
                await file.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(ms);

                ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
                using var package = new ExcelPackage(ms);
                var workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets["Stock"];
                totalRows = workSheet.Dimension.Rows;
                var gameList = new List<GameBank>();

                for (var i = 2; i <= totalRows; i++)
                {
                    gameList.Add(new GameBank
                    {
                        ProductDescription = workSheet.Cells[i, 1].Value.ToString(),
                        ProductCode = workSheet.Cells[i, 2].Value.ToString(),
                        UnitPrice = Convert.ToDouble(workSheet.Cells[i, 3].Value),
                        Quantity = Convert.ToInt16(workSheet.Cells[i, 4].Value),
                        Version = workSheet.Cells[i, 5].Value.ToString(),
                        Currency = workSheet.Cells[i, 6].Value.ToString(),
                        TotalPrice = Convert.ToDouble(workSheet.Cells[i, 7].Value),
                        Status = Convert.ToInt16(workSheet.Cells[i, 8].Value),
                        Used = Convert.ToInt16(workSheet.Cells[i, 9].Value),
                        RequestDateTime = DateTime.Now,
                        Signature = User.Identity.Name
                    });
                    gameList[i - 2].coupons = new GameBankPin
                    {
                        ExpiryDate = Convert.ToDateTime(workSheet.Cells[i, 10].Value),
                        Serial = workSheet.Cells[i, 11].Value.ToString(),
                        Pin = workSheet.Cells[i, 12].Value.ToString()
                    };
                }

                var existingRecords = await _stockUniqueSerialPinUseCase.ExecuteAsync(gameList);

                if (existingRecords.Count > 0)
                {
                    DownloadExcel(existingRecords);

                    duplicates = existingRecords.Count;

                }

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.LogError("{untrustedFileName} error on upload (Err: 3): {Message}",
                untrustedFileName, ex.Message);
        }
        return totalRows - 1 - duplicates;
    }

    private FileStreamResult Export(List<GameBank> existingRecords)
    {
        ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        var fileName = $"RazerDuplicateCodesList-{DateTime.Now:ddMMyyyyHHmm}.xlsx";

        using var package = new ExcelPackage(stream);
        var workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Duplicate Codes");
        workSheet.Protection.IsProtected = true;

        var recordIndex = 2;

        workSheet.Row(1).Style.Font.Bold = true;
        var headerCells = workSheet.Cells["A1:B1"];
        headerCells.Style.Font.Bold = true;
        headerCells.Style.Font.Size = 13;
        headerCells.Style.Border.BorderAround(ExcelBorderStyle.Thin);
        headerCells.Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
        headerCells.Style.Border.Left.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
        headerCells.Style.Border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
        headerCells.Style.Border.Bottom.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
        headerCells.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
        headerCells = workSheet.Cells["A1:B1"];
        // Set their background color to DarkBlue.
        headerCells.Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
        headerCells.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.LightGray);

        workSheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Serial";
        workSheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Pin";

        foreach (var duplicate in existingRecords)
        {
            workSheet.Cells[recordIndex, 1].Value = duplicate.coupons.Serial;
            workSheet.Cells[recordIndex, 2].Value = duplicate.coupons.Pin;
            recordIndex++;
        }

        //Make all text fit the cells
        workSheet.Cells[workSheet.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();
        package.SaveAsync();
        stream.Position = 0;

        return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet") { FileDownloadName = fileName };

    }

}
```

After successfully uploading Excel, I am generating another Excel and want to download this new Excel. There are no any errors and no download starting either. What is missing, What am I doing wrong?

By the way, I can download Excel from a razor page with IJSRuntime. But I couldn't download Excel in the controller.

Comment: Well, you aren't really doing anthing with the return value of your method `DownloadExcel` - so why should something happen?

Comment: Here is the answer to my problem, hope helps somebody else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code to my problem.

```
public async Task<int[]> UploadStocksFile(IFormFile file)
{
    var untrustedFileName = file.FileName;
    var totalRows = 0;
    var duplicates = 0;
    var result = new int[2];
    try
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath,
            env.EnvironmentName, "unsafe_uploads_stock",
            untrustedFileName);

        await using FileStream fs = new(path, FileMode.Create);
        await file.CopyToAsync(fs);

        logger.LogInformation("{untrustedFileName} saved at {Path}",
            untrustedFileName, path);

        var fi = new FileInfo(path);
        // Check if the file exists
        if (!fi.Exists)
            throw new Exception("File " + path + " Does Not Exists");

        //Check if file is an Excel File
        if (untrustedFileName.Contains(".xls"))
        {
            using var ms = new MemoryStream();
            await file.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(ms);

            ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
            using var package = new ExcelPackage(ms);
            var workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets["Stock"];
            totalRows = workSheet.Dimension.Rows;
            var gameList = new List<GameBank>();

            for (var i = 2; i <= totalRows; i++)
            {
                gameList.Add(new GameBank
                {
                    ProductDescription = workSheet.Cells[i, 1].Value.ToString(),
                    ProductCode = workSheet.Cells[i, 2].Value.ToString(),
                    UnitPrice = Convert.ToDouble(workSheet.Cells[i, 3].Value),
                    Quantity = Convert.ToInt16(workSheet.Cells[i, 4].Value),
                    Version = workSheet.Cells[i, 5].Value.ToString(),
                    Currency = workSheet.Cells[i, 6].Value.ToString(),
                    TotalPrice = Convert.ToDouble(workSheet.Cells[i, 7].Value),
                    Status = Convert.ToInt16(workSheet.Cells[i, 8].Value),
                    Used = Convert.ToInt16(workSheet.Cells[i, 9].Value),
                    RequestDateTime = DateTime.Now,
                    Signature = User.Identity.Name
                });
                gameList[i - 2].coupons = new GameBankPin
                {
                    ExpiryDate = Convert.ToDateTime(workSheet.Cells[i, 10].Value),
                    Serial = workSheet.Cells[i, 11].Value.ToString(),
                    Pin = workSheet.Cells[i, 12].Value.ToString()
                };
            }

            var existingRecords = await _stockUniqueSerialPinUseCase.ExecuteAsync(gameList);

            if (existingRecords.Count > 0)
            {
                duplicates = existingRecords.Count;
                await Export(existingRecords);
            }

        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.LogError("{untrustedFileName} error on upload (Err: 3): {Message}",
            untrustedFileName, ex.Message);
    }

    result[0] = totalRows - 1;
    result[1] = duplicates;

    return result;
}

private async Task Export(List<GameBank> existingRecords)
{
    ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    var fileName = $"RazerDuplicateCodesList-{DateTime.Now:ddMMyyyyHHmm}.xlsx";

    using var package = new ExcelPackage(stream);
    var workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Duplicate Codes");
    workSheet.Protection.IsProtected = true;

    var recordIndex = 2;

    workSheet.Row(1).Style.Font.Bold = true;
    var headerCells = workSheet.Cells["A1:B1"];
    headerCells.Style.Font.Bold = true;
    headerCells.Style.Font.Size = 13;
    headerCells.Style.Border.BorderAround(ExcelBorderStyle.Thin);
    headerCells.Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
    headerCells.Style.Border.Left.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
    headerCells.Style.Border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
    headerCells.Style.Border.Bottom.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
    headerCells.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
    headerCells = workSheet.Cells["A1:B1"];
    // Set their background color to DarkBlue.
    headerCells.Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
    headerCells.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.LightGray);

    workSheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Serial";
    workSheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Pin";

    try
    {
        foreach (var duplicate in existingRecords)
        {
            workSheet.Cells[recordIndex, 1].Value = duplicate.coupons.Serial;
            workSheet.Cells[recordIndex, 2].Value = duplicate.coupons.Pin;
            recordIndex++;
        }

        //Make all text fit the cells
        workSheet.Cells[workSheet.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();
        await package.SaveAsync();

        var path = Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath,
            env.EnvironmentName, "unsafe_uploads_stock",
            fileName);

        await using FileStream fs = new(path, FileMode.Create);
        await package.SaveAsAsync(fs);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception($@"Excel chart creation has failed for [{fileName}].\n{ex.Message}", ex);
    }


}
```